# Algorithms find the most frequently occurring sequence of strings of length 3

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

"Given multiple name arrays, find the most frequently occurring sequence of names of length 3(sequence of length 3), if it exists"

Eg:
Given 3 name arrays:

```
Ana John Maria
Paul
Sharon Ana John Maria Tiffany Ted
```

The output will be `Ana John Maria` since this sequence is encountered twice, in the first and the 3rd array.

i can't seem to find a correct solution for this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Maybe it's a well known algorihm for this. Can anyone give me a link?
Thanks

Comment: You could just count each word, then compare the counts. Not the most elegant solution, but probably the simplest.

Comment: @oleksii it's a sequence of length 3

Comment: Is it an array with 3 name(-sequences) or is it 3 arrays each with a couple of names in them?

Comment: @DanDinu:Are you interested in a specific programming language?

Answer (score 4):

Merge the arrays into a tree similar to trie, where each node is not a single letter, but a whole name. This should allow you to find and count subsequences more easily. In fact, I strongly suspect that there is a standard algorithm for this task which you can look up.

Update: Look at algorithms using suffix trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to take sequences of 3 and put them in a `HashTable`. As soon as you encounter a sequence of 3 you increment the corresponding occurence counter. In the end just return the most frequent occurence/sequence.This is found by scanning the `HashTable` for the entry with the max occurence value. Example in Java:

```
public class Sequence {  
     public List<String> sequenceOfThree(List<List<String>> names){
          Map<List<String>, Integer> map = new HashMap<List<String>, Integer>();  
          for(List<String> nameList:names){  
              int startIdx = 0;
              int endIdx = 3;
              while(endIdx <= nameList.size()){  
                   List<String> subsequence = nameList.subList(startIdx, endIdx);  
                   //add to map  
                   Integer count = map.get(subsequence);  
                   if(count == null){  
                         count = 0;  
                   }  
                   map.put(subsequence, count + 1);  
                   startIdx++;  
                   endIdx++;  
              }  
          }  
          Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  
          List<String> result = Collections.emptyList();  
          for(Entry<List<String>, Integer> entries:map.entrySet()){  
              if(entries.getValue() > max){  
                  max = entries.getValue();  
                  result = entries.getKey();  
          }
      }  
      return result;  
  }  
  /**  
   * @param args  
  */  
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
         List<List<String>> names = new ArrayList<List<String>>();  
         names.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Ana", "John", "Maria"}));  
         names.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Paul"}));  
         names.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]  
{"Sharon", "Ana", "John", "Maria", "Tiffany" ,"Ted"}));  
        System.out.println(new Sequence().sequenceOfThree(names));  
   }  
}
```

Comment: For some reason indentation is messed up

Comment: While this will work, the time will blow up as the input gets larger.

Comment: It is `O(MN)` where `M` is the number of lists and `N` the size of the list

Comment: @Marcin:On the other hand how much time to **construct** the tree instead?(Not the search for max occurence)

Comment: @Marcin:`Constructing such a tree for the string S takes time and space linear in the length of S`. Here we have `M` strings of length `N` or `S` so isn't it also `O(MN)` or `O(MS)`?

Comment: I think so. I suppose the question is whether there is a high constant factor for either method. Your method will involve a lot of concatenation and/or array allocation. A method similar to the one I suggest will involve allocating a number of smaller objects.

Comment: Also, how have you gotten to 10k without bothering with a real username?

Comment: @Marcin:Well I use `sublist` in the algorithm which does not copy anything (it is a view backed by the original `ArrayList`).So I don't see a downfall here.The only difference would be I think in terms of space. The tree would have no repeating sequences and they could be compressed.So runtime seems the same.But overall, I agree that using a tree would be an appropriate datastructure